# Why the WordPress "Post name" permalink settings stops to work in this WP website?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, content-management-system, permalinks

I am not so into WordPress and PHP and I have the following problem.

Som years ago I made this website for an humanitarian association: http://www.asper-eritrea.com/

Some days ago they have some problem (I think that they have make some update or something like this).

The problem is that all the internal links of the website stops to works.

For example trying to open posts I obtain a **404 error** message:

http://www.asper-eritrea.com/dallitalia-in-sostegno-alla-commissione-onu-per-i-diritti-umani-in-eritrea-il-23-giugno-la-manifestazione-internazionale-a-ginevra/

I noticed that changing the **permalink** settings from **Post name** to **Plain** it works fine but they need the **Post name** settings for a better indicization.

What could be the problem? Maybe something related to the **.htaccess** file?

This is the content of my **.htaccess** file:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

What am I missing? How can I try to fix this issue?

Comment: I just tried clicking around on the site and I cannot get a 404 error, everything seems fine. The link you posted works, and it also seems the links are set to post name. Are you still getting the error? Sometimes, after an update, it can just be fixed by changing the permalink settings and setting them back o post name again.

Comment: @LL it is paranormal: It didn't works, I switched permalink settings to "Plain" and it works as plain, then I switched again to "Post name" and it return to works as expected

Comment: Yes, sometimes the permalinks need to be saved again after an update. Glad it's resolved!